# How to render material top tab navigator inside a custom header component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-top-tabs

I would like to render material top tab navigator created with `createMaterialTopTabNavigator()` from `react-navigation` inside a custom header component.
Indeed, my header is a gradient, so I need to have tabs into the header like this:

[image]

So I set a `marginTop` negative on the tab bar to have it on the header:

```
// AppNavigator.ts
function MyTabStack() {
  const TabStack = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

  return (
    <TabStack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="MyTabScreen1"
      lazy={true}
      style={{
        marginTop: -40 - 14,
        zIndex: 1,
      }}
      tabBarOptions={{
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          height: 50,
        },
      }}>
      <TabStack.Screen
        name="MyTabScreen1"
        component={MyTabScreen1}
        options={{ title: 'Tab 1' }}
      />
      <TabStack.Screen
        name="MyTabScreen2"
        component={MyTabScreen2}
        options={{ title: 'Tab 2' }}
      />
    </TabStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode="screen" initialRouteName="MyScreen">
        <StackFidelity.Screen
           name="MyScreen"
           options={() => ({
             header: ({ options }) => <MyGradientHeader {...options} />,
          })}
          component={MyTabStack}
       />
       </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

It works well on Android, but not on iOS because tab bar is behind the header (I don't know why).
I can reporduce on expo (web version): [Expo link](https://snack.expo.dev/@francois-xavier/material-top-tabs-navigator-%7C-react-navigation)
Do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I remove header from my top Navigator

```
function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="MyScreen">
            <StackFidelity.Screen
                name="MyScreen"
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
                component={MyTabStack}
       />
       </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And create a custom tab component (`CustomTabHeader`) with gradiant and tab which I used as header

```
function MyTabStack() {
    const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="LittleCardsScene"
      tabBarPosition="top"
      tabBar={(props) => <CustomTabHeader {...props} />}
.....
```